# How to pass C# class object to managed c++ without unsafe modifier?

Tags: c#, powershell, c++-cli, managed, managed-c++

I am passing a C# object (PSObject) to managed C++ in the following way. But it crashes in the commented statement. Am I missing something?

**Am I passing PSObject correctly to managed C++?**
or am I accessing it wrongly?

I am using `clr:oldsyntax`.

Actually C# will pass a PSObject to managed C++,
in managed C++ I want to examine the properties present in PSObject. (An object returned by running PowerShell commands)

In C#, using delegate concept I am calling managed C++ method to pass PSObject.
The delegate is declared as below:

```
delegate bool CFuncDelegate(PSObject Arg);
```

funcObj (a IntPtr) is a pointer to `addData` function in C++ (I didn't write that code here, since it is not relevant) and I am calling addData in csharp as:

```
CFuncDelegate func = (CFuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcObj, typeof(CFuncDelegate));
bool isCompleted = func(psoObject); //psoObject is a PSObject
```

and in managed C++,

```
static bool __clrcall addData(System::Management::Automation::PSObject* curPsObj)
{
    log(Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(curPsObj->AdaptedMemberSetName));  
    //prints psadapted

    System::Object* value = curPsObj->Properties->get_Item("DisplayName");   
    //crashes
}
```

It would be better if someone just post two lines of code to pass object from C# and accessing it in managed C++. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's really time that you abandoned `oldsyntax` and moved to C++/CLI. Anyway, even doing that is not going to solve your problem. You define a delegate like this:

```
delegate bool CFuncDelegate(PSObject Arg);
```

And then you assign a delegate variable like this:

```
CFuncDelegate func = (CFuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
    funcObj, typeof(CFuncDelegate));
```

The [documentation for `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zdx6dyyh.aspx) says:

> Converts an unmanaged function pointer to a delegate.

So, your code can only work if `funcObj` is an unmanaged function. And your `addData` method is certainly not that. You need to stop using `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` here. It is simply not compatible with calling the managed function `addData`.

I've no idea where `funcObj` comes from. You said:

> funcObj (a IntPtr) is a pointer to addData function in cpp (i didnt write that code here, since it is not relevant)

In fact it is not only relevant to the problem, it is the root cause of the problem. What I would expect to see here would be for you to add the C++ assembly to your C# project as a reference, at which point `addData` could be referenced directly.

Of course, none of this even mentions the fact that your calling conventions are mis-matched. The managed code uses `clrcall` and your unmanaged function pointer is taken to be `stdcall`.

**Update**

There's some more information in the comments. Pass `addData` as a delegate. You'll need to declare the delegate type in the C# code which I believe you reference from your C++ assembly.

Comment: Hi, First thing:
csharp code is a .netmodule, only my managed cpp is dependent on .netmodule not the other way around.

Just saw that documentation. But contrary to it, the function is getting called successfully. It just crashes in the statement i commented.

and regarding funcObj,

It is declared in c# as,

    `IntPtr funcObj;`

in manged cpp, when creating the object for csharp class, i will pass:
    `System::IntPtr(addData)`
as one of the argument for csharp constructor.
In csharp cons, i will initialize funcObj (one of its instance variable of type IntPtr):
    `this.funcObj = funcObj;`

Comment: It is crashing for the reason I said.

Comment: thank you David, may be that is the reason.. but i want to pass a PSObject to managed cpp from c#. When one of the argument of a function in managed cpp is of type managed object (in my case PSObject), i cant specify stdcall as the calling convention. (compile time error). So how can i pass PSObject to managed cpp? kindly guide me..

Comment: Do it the way I said in the update to my answer. Stop thinking you've got an unmanaged pointer. Also, it's not fair to ask for detailed advice when you did not tell us where funcObj comes from. That's where your problem is. But if you won't tell us where it comes from how can you expect us to give detailed help.